# How do I convert a recursive algorithm that calls itself more than one time?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

I have a function that calls itself 2 times in its body, and I want to make it non recursive using a stack.

I have the following to to find the depth of a binary tree. It works but I need to convert it to a non recursive function.
I was thinking about using a `stack` but this function calls itself twice in its code, one for each side. How do I accomplish the requirement?

This is my code so far

```cpp
struct Node{
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

int depth(const Node* n){
    // 0 if null
    if(n == nullptr) return 0;
    // max(d(left), d(right)) + 1 otherwise
    return max(depth(n->left), depth(n->right)) + 1;
}

int depthNoRecursion(const Node* n){
        std::stack<Node*> s;
        // Do something here...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it?  Traversing a tree is a natural fit for a recursive algorithm, unless the tree is very deep.

Comment: Take a crack at solving it yourself and if you don't get it working the way you want it, THEN ask a question. Asking without doing makes you look lazy and tends to result in 100% correct but 100% useless answers like "Do what the recursion does, except in a loop."

Comment: *"...make it non recursive using a stack"* - or maybe a *queue*.

Comment: "function that calls itself 2 times in its body" - it has two recursive invocations, but the number of times each might be called is determined by the tree size.

Comment: The question would be better received if there was more progress on your end toward a solution. Try this as an exercise: instead of returning `max(depth(n->left), depth(n->right)) + 1`, start with a function that returns simply `depth(n->left) + 1`. I know this is not what you want, but could you convert this exercise to a non-recursive function using a stack? If you can, please show us -- that would be a great starting point for the more complex case. (If you cannot, focus on the simpler case first.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using a stack of pair that keep the node itself and the current level, something like that

```
stack<pair<Node*, int>> stk;
stk.push({root, 1});
int mx_depth = 0;
while(stk.size()){
   auto tp = stk.top();
   mx_depth = max(mx_depth, tp.second);
   stk.pop();
   if(tp.first->left != nullptr)
      stk.push({tp.first->left, tp.second + 1});
  if(tp.first->right != nullptr)
      stk.push({tp.first->right, tp.second + 1});
}
```